# Allow shipping that is calculated using a base rate plus a rate per item?

Tags: 8, commerce

I figured this would be built in, but it seems it is not. See here:

[image]

I have two options:

1. Flat rate: I can make it 9.99 USD, but then if it's 100 items, it's still 9.99 USD.
2. I can make it 1 USD per item, but I als don't want that.

What I want is a base rate of 10 USD, and then 1 USD per item after that. Anyone know how to do that?

*UPDATE*

There is some information available for Commerce 1.0 [here](https://vimeo.com/32813567), but hardly any information on Commerce 2. [This](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/shipping) is basically all there is.

Can it be that Commerce 2 doesn't support this? I mean, nowhere can I see "shipping rules" or anything related to that that allows me to set up these rules?

(I miss UberCart)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programmatically create your own custom shipping method in a custom module.

Example, custom module called "mymodule":

/modules/custom/mymodule/src/Plugin/Commerce/ShippingMethod/**CustomRate.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Commerce\ShippingMethod;

use Drupal\commerce_shipping\Plugin\Commerce\ShippingMethod\ShippingMethodBase;
use Drupal\commerce_price\Price;
use Drupal\commerce_shipping\Entity\ShipmentInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_shipping\PackageTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_shipping\ShippingRate;
use Drupal\commerce_shipping\ShippingService;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\state_machine\WorkflowManagerInterface;

/**
 * Provides the FlatRatePerItem shipping method.
 *
 * @CommerceShippingMethod(
 *   id = "custom_rate",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom Rate"),
 * )
 */
class CustomRate extends ShippingMethodBase {

  /**
   * Constructs a new FlatRate object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\commerce_shipping\PackageTypeManagerInterface $package_type_manager
   *   The package type manager.
   * @param \Drupal\state_machine\WorkflowManagerInterface $workflow_manager
   *   The workflow manager.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, PackageTypeManagerInterface $package_type_manager, WorkflowManagerInterface $workflow_manager) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $package_type_manager, $workflow_manager);

    $this->services['default'] = new ShippingService('default', $this->configuration['rate_label']);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return [
        'rate_label' => '',
        'rate_description' => '',
        'rate_amount' => NULL,
        'services' => ['default'],
      ] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    $amount = $this->configuration['rate_amount'];
    // A bug in the plugin_select form element causes $amount to be incomplete.
    if (isset($amount) && !isset($amount['number'], $amount['currency_code'])) {
      $amount = NULL;
    }
    // A bug in the plugin_select form element causes $base_amount to be undefined.
    if (!empty($this->configuration['base_amount'])) {
      $base_amount = $this->configuration['base_amount'];
    }
    else {
      $base_amount = null;
    }

    $form['rate_label'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Rate label'),
      '#description' => t('Shown to customers when selecting the rate.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['rate_label'],
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    $form['rate_description'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Rate description'),
      '#description' => t('Provides additional details about the rate to the customer.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['rate_description'],
    ];
    $form['base_amount'] = [
      '#type' => 'commerce_price',
      '#title' => t('Base amount'),
      '#default_value' => $base_amount,
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#description' => t('Charged once.'),
    ];
    $form['rate_amount'] = [
      '#type' => 'commerce_price',
      '#title' => t('Rate amount'),
      '#default_value' => $amount,
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#description' => t('Charged for each quantity of each shipment item.'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    if (!$form_state->getErrors()) {
      $values = $form_state->getValue($form['#parents']);
      $this->configuration['rate_label'] = $values['rate_label'];
      $this->configuration['rate_description'] = $values['rate_description'];
      $this->configuration['base_amount'] = $values['base_amount'];
      $this->configuration['rate_amount'] = $values['rate_amount'];
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function calculateRates(ShipmentInterface $shipment) {
    $base_amount = Price::fromArray($this->configuration['base_amount']); // create base price
    $amount = Price::fromArray($this->configuration['rate_amount']);
    $quantity = $shipment->getTotalQuantity();
    $ship_price = $amount->multiply($quantity);
    $ship_price = $ship_price->add($base_amount); // add base
    $rates = [];
    $rates[] = new ShippingRate([
      'shipping_method_id' => $this->parentEntity->id(),
      'service' => $this->services['default'],
      'amount' => $ship_price,
    ]);

    return $rates;
  }

}
```

### Result

[image]